# Are Web Notifications Supported on Microsoft Edge Mobile?

Tags: microsoft-edge, windows-10-mobile, web-notifications

Recently I heard that Microsoft Edge mobile supports Web Notifications after the Windows 10 Anniversary Update. So I tried the following code but it didn't work.

```js
if ( window.Notification && Notification.permission !== "denied" ) {
    Notification.requestPermission( function( status ) { // status is "granted", if accepted by user
        var n = new Notification('Title', { 
            body: 'I am the body text!',
            icon: '/path/to/icon.png' // optional
        });
    });
}
```

I am on Windows 10 mobile using Edge 38.14393.67.0, and EdgeHTML 14.14393.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use it too, and I get instant denied response. I've made a ticket about this in the feedback hub.
(Update)
I've found their answer here. https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/MicrosoftEdge-Documentation/issues/62
So yes, it would be quite limited, but still. They say it's supported. 
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/webnotifications/